# How to load files/images in qt webkit from sqlite database?

Tags: qt, sqlite, webkit

I've got a bunch of encrypted data in SQLite via SQLCipher.
How can I load it into Qt WebKit?

I suppose that it can be done via definition of a new `QDirModel`.

Maybe there is another way to do so by using other crypto store method?

Answer (score 0):

#### SOLVED

I've reimplemented `QNetworkReply` and `QNetworkAccessManager`